# Ansible shell and perl script failing

Tags: perl, shell, ansible

I am trying to invoke a Perl script on my host machine using Ansible. The Perl script has to be executed by a specific user "PresenceUser". What I seeing is that although Ansible reports no errors the script is failing to execute and/or complete the job.

The task I have added to perform this action is this.

```
- name: Extract out Presence Collector application [Failing]
  shell: perl extract.pl PresenceCollector_{{ app_version }}.tbz
  become_user: PresenceUser
  args:
    chdir: "{{ app_path }}"
  tags:
    - application_install
  register: result

- debug: var=result.stdout_lines
  tags:
    - application_install
```

The result from Ansible shows this

```
TASK [presencecollector : Extract out Presence Collector application [Failing]]
    task path: /home/vagrant/ansible/roles/presencecollector/tasks/main.yml:171
    <10.157.7.30> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ipasupport
    <10.157.7.30> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -vvv -F ssh.cfg -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=ipasupport -o ConnectTimeout=30 10.157.7.30 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /tmp/ansible-tmp-1470308291.94-99052579867678 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1470308291.94-99052579867678="` echo /tmp/ansible-tmp-1470308291.94-99052579867678 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
    <10.157.7.30> PUT /tmp/tmptI8322 TO /tmp/ansible-tmp-1470308291.94-99052579867678/command
    <10.157.7.30> SSH: EXEC sftp -b - -C -vvv -F ssh.cfg -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=ipasupport -o ConnectTimeout=30 '[10.157.7.30]'
    <10.157.7.30> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ipasupport
    <10.157.7.30> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -vvv -F ssh.cfg -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=ipasupport -o ConnectTimeout=30 10.157.7.30 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'chown -R PresenceUser /tmp/ansible-tmp-1470308291.94-99052579867678/ && sleep 0'"'"''
    <10.157.7.30> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ipasupport
    <10.157.7.30> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -vvv -F ssh.cfg -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=ipasupport -o ConnectTimeout=30 10.157.7.30 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'setfacl -R -m u:PresenceUser:rX /tmp/ansible-tmp-1470308291.94-99052579867678/ && sleep 0'"'"''
    <10.157.7.30> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ipasupport
    <10.157.7.30> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -vvv -F ssh.cfg -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=ipasupport -o ConnectTimeout=30 -tt 10.157.7.30 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'sudo -H -S  -p "[sudo via ansible, key=npvufcaonbexvxpysfwyugmowdjszfvb] password: " -u PresenceUser /bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-npvufcaonbexvxpysfwyugmowdjszfvb; LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python /tmp/ansible-tmp-1470308291.94-99052579867678/command'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''
    <10.157.7.30> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ipasupport
    <10.157.7.30> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -vvv -F ssh.cfg -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=ipasupport -o ConnectTimeout=30 10.157.7.30 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'rm -f -r /tmp/ansible-tmp-1470308291.94-99052579867678/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'"'"''
changed: [pres7] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "perl extract.pl PresenceCollector_1.0_PC_529.tbz", "delta": "0:00:00.095483", "end": "2016-08-04 11:30:09.972859", "invocation": {"module_args": {"_raw_params": "perl extract.pl PresenceCollector_1.0_PC_529.tbz", "_uses_shell": true, "chdir": "/home/PresenceUser/1.0_PC_22.0/", "creates": null, "executable": null, "removes": null, "warn": true}, "module_name": "command"}, "rc": 0, "start": "2016-08-04 11:30:09.877376", "stderr": "", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": [], "warnings": []}
```

The debug output shows nothing at all.

```
TASK [presencecollector : debug] ***********************************************
task path: /home/vagrant/ansible/roles/presencecollector/tasks/main.yml:180
ok: [pres7] => {
    "result.stdout_lines": []
}
```

If I login to that host as PresenceUser I can execute the command manually with success.

I tried with the Ansible "command" module as well and got the same results.

Something I did notice was that even though I specified the "shell" module, it shows that the module name is "command"?

Is there a way I can further debug what is happening when Ansible tries to execute the command.

Comment: One thing I tried was to see that if I run the command 'perl -c extract.pl' in the shell module and get the results. Strangely the perl check completes, but I see the "extract.pl synxtax OK" in stderr ?? I guess the issue is within the Perl script itself :-(

Comment: try putting `become_user` after the `args`. I'm not sure if Ansible will apply `args: chdir` to the shell command if it is not defined directly after the command.

Comment: The order in which keys are listed in the dictionary is irrelevant.  The YAML is parsed into a Python dictionary before it is processed by Ansible, so you have no control over the ordering of the keys.

Comment: You're printing `result.stdout_lines`, but what about `result.stderr_lines`?  Maybe just the verbatim output of `debug: var=result`.

Comment: I just updated my original post as I was missing some of the debug output. Here you can see that there is no output at all from the shell execution. Unfortunately I did not write the Perl script so I believe that could be the underlying issue here, not Ansible.

Answer (score 0):

Try quoting the entire value passed to the shell module and redirecting the stderror to stdout. Like:

```
- name: Extract out Presence Collector application
  shell: "perl extract.pl PresenceCollector_{{ app_version }}.tbz 2>&1"
  become_user: PresenceUser
  args:
    chdir: "{{ app_path }}"
  tags:
    - application_install
  register: result
```

Comment: I tried without quotes and single/double - same results all around. I agree that command is more appropriate. I decided to change to shell to see if it would change things.

Comment: OK, maybe your script is outputting to stderr only and not to stdout? Could you try adding a 2>&1 at the end of command line? (this will require the shell module)